# Correlation between Likert scale independent variables and multiple categorical dependent variables

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, spss, cronbachs-alpha

[image]

Based on the above diagram:

- My alpha for the independent variable is above 0.7
- My Alpha is negative for the dependent variable. (I tried reversing items with negative words and the option of if item deleted without success).

Despite that my N is over 900, I have no correlation between both variables, and I have several other independent variables besides the one in the picture above, also with no correlations. Why is there a negative alpha, and is that the reason there is no correlation?

My questions are: Is there any way to transform the dependent variable to Likert scale? Is that the reason or should I interpret it as it has been given? I mean shall I report the findings as it appears or there is a problem in the scaling and analysis? How can I overcome this?

My aim to find if there are any affect or impact of independent on the dependent variables.